# Visual studio - MVC Find usages of DisplayTemplate/EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-essentials

How can I find usages of single let's say editor template in Visual studio? Or maybe in other direction how can I goto template which is rendered with EditorFor?

Comment: Have you got ReSharper, as your tag edit suggests?

Comment: Yes I have resharper.

Comment: Hmm, this could be tricky since it depends so much on the MVC conventions.

Comment: Yes I know but is very annoying to look for display templates and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one workaround/help. If you have Visual Studio 2013 and Web Essentials installed you can CTRL+click anywhere on the page and the menu like this pops up.

[image]

If you click Inspect you can click on any element on page and then you cursor in Visual Studio moves to corresponding View/PartialView/DisplayTemplate/...

[Mads Kristensen post on Web essentials 2013](http://madskristensen.net/post/web-essentials-2013-rtm)